# I want to remove only one character before particular symbol for example:

Tags: javascript

I want to remove a specific character, as well as the one before it (in this case `#` and its preceding character). Example:

```
"ab#c" -> "ac"
```

Comment: A regex replace would work : `'ab#c'.replace(/.#/g,'')`

Answer (score 6):

Use a regex and [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const inp = "ab#c";
const match = /.#/;
const out = inp.replace(match, "");

console.log(out);
```

Note that this removes any character preceding a '#' in your original string, but only a single occurrence. Add the `g` flag to match and replace all occurrences, and use `[a-zA-Z]` to just match letters.

If you want to work the other way (character following, not preceding), and want to replace `#c` but not `\#c`, just add that as well:

```js
const inp = "ab\\#c3#cc";
const match = /[^\\]{1}#./;
const out = inp.replace(match, "");

console.log(out);
```

Comment: If I have `ab#c` and `ab\#c3#cc` and what to remove only `#c` that is not preceded by `\#c` would it be possible?

Comment: Yes, it is - I'll edit my answer to add that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global regex replace

```js
const inputStr = "ab#c de#f gh#i";

const regxStr = /.#/g;
const outputStr = inputStr.replace(regxStr, "");

console.log(outputStr);
```